# Laravel: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.5

I'm using Laravel 5.5. I've my database ready and i have 2 tables. 1) `users` 2) `users_auth_tokens` There's no any data filled in `users` table right now.

So, my requirement is for first time any third user call api to get `refreshToken` for android device and i will insert data(`'auth_token'`, `'refresh_token'`, `'token_validity'`) into `users_auth_tokens` table when it called. There's one field `user_id` which i want to insert `'0'` for first time api call and when any user make call api after login, i want to update same record(which is `user_id=0`) with the logged-in `user_id`.

But unfortunately, when i was trying to insert record with `user_id=0` it's give me error like:

> "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`tracker`.`users_auth_tokens`, CONSTRAINT
>   `users_auth_tokens_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES
>   `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into
>   `users_auth_tokens` (`auth_token`, `validity`, `refresh_token`,
>   `updated_at`, `created_at`) values
>   (ETZEI11RY3D7RQE4XR6OBTNQHC6Q1ND187E5FD3E45281D3385D784C3D89C0697D46DDC,
>   1524135471, b87c88fdcf1eea0a6680620d8da77e4f0ee18b78, 2018-04-19
>   10:52:51, 2018-04-19 10:52:51))"

I know that why this error occurs because there's foreign key `user_id` in `users_auth_tokens` and there's no any record in `users` table right now! I've tried with default 0 value from migration and make it nullable also, but no luck.

Anyway i want to insert `user_id=0` in that table. I search some tricks on google but no one helps.

My code is like:

```
$usersAuthTokens = new UsersAuthTokens;
$usersAuthTokens->auth_token = $authToken;
$usersAuthTokens->validity = $time;
$usersAuthTokens->refresh_token = $newRefreshToken;
$usersAuthTokens->user_id = 0;  //error is here..because no record in users table right now
$usersAuthTokens->save();
```

Anyone have an solution for this? Any helps will be appreciated!!

Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you create a row in Users table with some dummy user_id or 0 and then use it in user_auth_tokens table ?

Comment: Can you use `null` instead `0`? That would be a much more elegant solution.

Comment: @PraveenE: I understand your thoughts, but is there any other solution for this?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir: yes, i tried but no luck.

Comment: Did you make `users_auth_tokens.user_id` `nullable`?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir: yes, i tried to make nullable from migration as well as in phpmyadmin both, but no luck.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Do you get an error?

Comment: I got above error.: `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169329/discussion-between-jonas-staudenmeir-and-hiren-gohel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed it with saving `null` user_id but not with `0`.

I need to make `->nullable()` in migration file and when I am saving the record, I also need to save `null` value!

I tried to save `user_id=0` but no luck and I've fixed it with `null` value!

Thanks for your help @JonasStaudenmeir!

Hope this will helps any other user in the future if they face the same issue!